# What better? HTML image from url or server?

Tags: html, web, frontend

What better? HTML image from url or server?

I want to know what makes my site more faster

```
<img src="url">
```

or

```
<img src="image.jpg">
```

Comment: My instinct is to say it doesn't make a difference as you have to make another HTTP connection regardless but I'm not entirely sure as you would have to do another DNS lookup... Have you run it through [PageInsights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/?hl=en)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the speed of the server, it's data link and it's load than how you are going to refer to the image. Trying to optimize the quality of the image might give you a better edge than the reference method.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is by far to have it on you own server not for speed thoguh but if the server where your image is hosted goes down the image disappear